# How does one pass $ (list separator) as an parameter?

Tags: perl, parameters, global-variables, subroutine

There is this little piece of code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub checkDefinition {
    my ($var, $desc) = @_;

    if (defined $var) {
    print "$desc: $var \n";
    } else {
    print "$desc: undef \n";
    }
}

checkDefinition($ , "list separator");
```

however, when I try to run it, I receive the following error:

```
>perl listSeparator.pl String found where operator expected at listSeparator.pl line 14, near "$ , "list separator""
        (Missing operator before "list separator"?) syntax error at listSeparator.pl line 14, near "$ , "list separator"" Execution of
listSeparator.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

so, this begs the question, how does one pass the list separator variable to a subroutine?   I tried making a reference to it:

```
my $lineSepRef = \$ ;
```

however, I get another error:

```
Semicolon seems to be missing at listSeparator.pl line 14.
```

Is it possible to pass $ to a subroutine?   If so, how?

FYI, running on windows, strawberry perl version 5.016003

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am confused. What do you mean by "line separator"? The `$` symbol is used inside regular expressions to match with the end of line. But it's not a variable, you cannot use it that way outside a regular expression.

Comment: my understanding is that it is a special global variable that contains the line separator character.  At least according to [Perl in a Nutshell](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/perlnut/ch04_04.htm)

Comment: There is a typo in the link. The correct variable for the list separator is `$"` (see [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24LIST_SEPARATOR)).

Comment: @redneb - ok, well there is our problem.   That solved this.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's what you get for using dodgy copyright-violating sites instead of the [official documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess by "line separator" you mean the special (global) Perl variable `$/`, which is the *input record separator*.

You could pass the value of that to a subroutine like this, even when I don't see why you want to do that:

```
checkDefinition($/ , "list separator");
```

In case you mean another special variable, you could pass it the same way. You can find the meanings of all special Perl variables [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

EDIT:

Since you were actually looking for the "list separator", you can do the following:

```
checkDefinition($" , "list separator");
```

Comment: Thanks Inferno, but I think my reference material was incorrect.   I was looking for $" - the list separator - which was pointed out by rednab.

Comment: I added another example for this case. You can see it's basically the same thing, just another variable.